# Examples of path component maps

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I understand what needs to be done for the first part, i have to somehow map $1$ point onto $1$ point, in a map where there exists $2$ points... so the inverse map is injective, but how is this possible?

For the second point, i dont fully understand how i can show this, do i show $f_*$ is bijective but $f$ is not continuous?

Comment: For the second point, can you think of a path connected space which is not a point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the projection on the first component. Then, f is not injective but induces a bijection $f_{\ast}:\pi_0(\mathbb{R}^{n+m})\rightarrow \pi_0(\mathbb{R}^{m})$, since $\pi_0(\mathbb{R}^{n+m})$ and $\pi_0(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ both are one point sets.

This also solves the second question, because $f_{\ast}$ is bijective but $f$ is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: i understand how this solves the first point, however, how have you concluded that we have one point sets in order to show the second point?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is connected so the set of path components of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ has one element only.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler than that. Take the map $f$ from $X:=\mathbb{R}$ to $Y:=\{0\}$. Then $f$ is continuous and certainly not one to one.

However $X$ and $Y$ are both path-connected so $f_*$ has all the condition needed.

Comment: From this i understand how this solves the first point, however, would this also solve the second point?

Comment: @smith $f_*$ is bijective and $f$ is not injective so yes it works for the second point too.

Comment: can you explain why $f_*$ is bijective? i can't fully see this?

Comment: @smith, $\pi_0(X)$ and $\pi_0(Y)$ are both sets with one element so $f_*$ cannot but be bijective.